# How can I get a lot of wool in Minecraft: XBox 360 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am embarking on a construction project that will require hundreds and hundreds of blocks of colored wool. Thus far, after all my adventuring, I have about 70. Is there a way I can practically mass-produce wool? I don't want to have to roam around looking for 500 sheep.

Sheep seem to spawn and despawn randomly, and they don't breed on XBox, so I don't know if they are farmable. Even if they're not, is there a way to encourage them to spawn or congregate? Or, is there any other way to get wool?

Comment: I don't have the Xbox edition, but I think that in the version of MC you're running there's no way to farm sheep - they don't regrow their wool so it's just a matter of hunting them down. Remember to dye sheep *before* killing them - it's more economical on dye.

Comment: In order to prevent animal abuse on the xbox, it it now more profitable to use shears rather than punching sheep in the face to get their wool. Just a heads up to all you sheep punchers out there.

Comment: @hammythepig Actually, murdering sheep would be better - after you've shorn them of course. As sheep don't regrow their wool you want more to spawn sooner, so reducing mob-count is more efficient! Face-punch away!

Comment: @QAdley You mean there is actually an excuse? :D You'd be an inspiration at our Sheep Punchers Anonymous meetings. 6 o'clock Thursdays.

Comment: @hammythepig The murdererer the merrier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Create a well lit area of grass in the middle of a desert biome.
2. Wait until nightfall.
3. Many passive mobs will spawn, as it's the only place they can.
4. Shear any sheep that spawn, then brutally murder them.
5. Also brutally murder *all* other passive mobs, to up the spawn rate
6. ???????
7. Profit.

Comment: desert biome, never thought of that. No one to hear them scream! ... or baaa

Answer (score 3):

Sheep tend to spawn a lot more in mountainous regions and plains. Since sheep don't regrow their wool yet, the best method would be to use shears, kill them, then wait for more to respawn.

Answer (score 2):

Sheep will only spawn on grass blocks, so creating an area where the only grass blocks are in an enclosed area will ensure that you have a supply of sheep to shear.

I suggest an island or in the ocean to create you sheepy paradise.

If you were to set to a mob farmer you can separate your sheep and cows from other mobs using their size and floating abilities.

Comment: Would a large underground area work, if I could get some grass down there? I have a great island but not sure if I want to pave over it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wheat on them to make them breed with other sheep.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to farm my sheep in the xbox 360 edition of minecraft. I created a large, above ground building (it didnt work when i did it underground) and created seperate pens for the sheep. In it are 12 pens for the colors i wanted. Each pen has a total of 16squares for the sheep. (Sheep will despaen if they have 20 ormote squares to roam). I keep 3 per pen. There is a glass roof so they still get sunlight and grass is available to the. I can sheer them and their wool grows back. Ilater built a second building of a similar nature so i can have even more sheep. Issues you want to be careful of:
-make sure that they have have less than 20 squares to walk in per pen.
-i suggest do not have more than 3 in a pen. It starts to be a bit glitchy.
-make sure to have a glass roof so that the sun can create more grass
-and becareful of walls. If you use a fence, make sure its double layered. WOLVES CAN KILL SHEEP THROUGH ONE LAYER OF FENCE. It was happening to me for the longest time.
- i suggest that once your sheep are in pens, replace the gate with a door. They cant get through a door, so its not as troublesome when you try and get in and out of each pen. (I created a halway behind each pen so i can get in and out through doors easily and still have gates on the front of pens so i can move sheep if need be).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Just get one wool and do what it tells you to do do and you will have a billion wool for ever.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but first off, this is a glitch at best, and cheating at worst. Second off, I believe this glitch was fixed in the July update and no longer works.

Comment: It still works for me but if you don't want to cheat that's fine I understand